# How to query images from the db in django

Tags: python, django

How can i query images from the database. i have a form where a user can upload an image and on someother page i want to display the images uploaded which are user specific

Answer (score 3):

Django doesn't store image files into database, it stores the file path.

There is an example:
[image]

You can do something like this:

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...


class UserUpload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/your/image/files/path')
```

to query all uploaded files from a user in a view for example just do:

```
class DummyExampleView(View):
    template = 'path/to/file.html'

    def get(self, request):
        images = UserUpload.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, self.template, locals())
```

If you really want to store images in the database, you can convert the uploaded image to a `base64` string and store it into a `models.Charfield`, but the storage cost is high.

Comment: it's also worth noticing that the user needs to have access to that path

Comment: @Shinratensei Not exactly. In production, these files are served by NGINX or the server of your choice since Django doesn't serve static files in production.

Comment: Yes, in production.

Comment: But if images do not get stored in db, than how will it bring images from a particular user

Comment: @PrathamDave In the example above, the registration of an upload in the database necessarily needs a `user` instance due to `Foreign Key` relationship, so you will know who this image belongs to. If you are concerned with filename conflicts,  Django automatically renames the file in these cases. If you want to manage filename by hand, you can pass a method in the `upload_file_to` param. If you want more details I add above.